# How to align a div with the right of a table?

Tags: css

I have a structure like this:

```
<table id="A">
...
</table>
<div id="B">some lefty text</div>
<div id="C">some righty text</div>
```

What I need is to align B to the left edge of the table, and align C with its right edge, so that I end up with:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBB               CCCC
```

I'm stuck on how to do this in CSS. I've tried floating C to the right, but this puts C at the right of the entire window, rather than aligned to the right of the table even if I enclose everything in an outer DIV.

None of the elements are of fixed size, but it's a reasonable assumption that the sum of width of the contents B and the width of the content of C are less than the width of the content of A. (i.e. the diagram is a plausible layout for the content). The solution needs to work in IE8+.

Comment: Tried that. <div> doesn't shrink to size of table. But @Jon's answer below is correct.

Comment: wrap table and content under it in div and display as inline block http://jsfiddle.net/7R2qS/ , then just float right and left

Comment: Thanks @user1525612 - Jon just pipped you to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all three pieces of content in a container and give it `display: inline-block` so that it shrinks to fit the width of its contents (given the description this will be the width of the table).

After doing this the `float` solution you describe will work as intended.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/BGqpn/)**.

Comment: +1 Wow! Answered within 4 minutes of me asking with a live example as well. So fast I can't mark this as answered yet. Thanks.

Comment: Downvoter: Please help me improve this answer by leaving a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the table in a div and then float the divs

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QWSmg/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table id="A">
        <tr>
            <td>table</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="B">some lefty text</div>
    <div id="C">some righty text</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table, div {
    border:1px solid #999;
}
table {
    width:100%;
}
#B {
    float:left;
}
#C {
    float:right;
}
#wrapper {
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Note that a key limitation was that none of the sizes could be fixed.

Comment: What size is fixed? I set the wrapper to 50% width only to illustrate the effect.

Comment: table width 100% confused me.

Comment: I see. Well the answer is not dependent on the wrapper width.

Answer (score 1):

try using a wrapper around your divs.

```
<div id="wrap">
  <table id="A">
  ...
  </table>
  <div id="B">some lefty text</div>
  <div id="C">some righty text</div>
</div> <!-- end wrap -->
```

Set the Wrap size to whatever u want your full table to be, and set table to 100%
Say with a 500px width table it would be somehting like this:

```
#wrap {
position: relative;
width: 500px;
}

table {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

#a{
float: left;
}

#b{
float: right;
}
```

Comment: Note that a key limitation was that none of the sizes could be fixed.

Comment: Sorry, missed that :) I'd say that the answer above with the "display:inline block" is probably the best then.